# Does a smart contract at V2 or V3 indicate that it is an upgradeable contract?

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, contract-upgrading

Uniswap's smart contract is now known as "Uniswap V3" to delineate from earlier versions. Does this call sign imply that Uniswap V1 was an **upgradeable contract** all along? How about "SuperRare V2"'s contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just naming. You can't figure out upgradeability just by looking at the name.

In the case of Uniswap, they don't use upgradeability at all. They simply deploy new versions and modify their frontend to use the new contracts at the new addresses.